# What's the difference between XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter) and XElement.Save(XmlWriter)?

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

What's the difference between `XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter)` and `XElement.Save(XmlWriter)`? Or are they the same?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.save#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_Save_System_Xml_XmlWriter_

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.writeto#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_WriteTo_System_Xml_XmlWriter_

Comment: The WriteTo() uses the older Xml Library while the Save() uses the Xml Linq library.  The results should be the same.

Comment: I think you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`XElement.Save(XmlWriter)`** writes a full xml document to the target `XmlWriter`, including the start and end document declarations.
To write the content of the `XElement` itself, it calls the same `WriteTo` method.

From the [.NET reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,4320):

```
public void Save(XmlWriter writer)
{
    if (writer == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
    }
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    WriteTo(writer);
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

**`XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter)`** just writes the given `XElement` to the target `XmlWriter`.

From the [.NET reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,4420):

```
public override void WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
{
    if (writer == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
    }
    new ElementWriter(writer).WriteElement(this);
}
```

This allows the `XElement` to be included in an `XmlWriter` already containing any other xml nodes, eg. a custom root xml element as shown below.
Also multiple `XElement.WriteTo` calls can be made upon the same `XmlWriter`.

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse("<foo>bar</foo>");

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();    
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");

    xml.WriteTo(writer);

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}

Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

The above results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
   <foo>bar</foo>
</root>
```